# Flow of fluid through a really tricky closed surface S (divergence theorem)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

Considering a fluid whose velocity field is

$\vec{v}(x,y,z)= (y^{3}e^{-z^{2}} + x)\vec{i} + (ze^{x} + y^{2})\vec{j} + (cos(x^{2}+ y^{2}) +2z)\vec{k}$

Calculate the flow of fluid through the closed surface S comprises the border of the area bounded by the half-spheres $z = -\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}$ and $z = \sqrt{9-x^{2}-y^{2}}$ and by the plan  $z = 0$.

For the moment, I calculated the divergence of $\vec{v}$ to apply the divergence theorem in the volume of the cap between the half-spheres using cylindrical coordinates and I found a answer. But I'm not sure if I need to do something special in reason of the minus sign in the first half-sphere.

I'm afraid of doing something really wrong because I don't understand the divergence theorem really well. So any tip will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the spheres dont fit together, is it a non smooth surface ?

Comment: Probably not the best question to do if your new to divergence theorem, but have you calculated the divergence ?

Comment: Yes I did @Rene Schipperus. I found $ div \ \vec{v} = 2z + 3$

Comment: I think its $2y+3$, but ok just integrate this over the two half spheres.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus. I really don't know why I wrote 2z instead of the 2y :/ I found 38$\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Volume of Integration is created by the overlapping of two semi-spheres centered at the origin ($S_1$ being the upper sphere, and $S_2$ being the lower one).

$\nabla\cdot\vec{u}=1+2y+2=3+2y$

$\begin{eqnarray}
\displaystyle\iint\limits_{\partial S_1\mathop\cup\partial S_2}\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n}\,\mathrm dS&=&\iiint\limits_{S_1\mathop\cup S_2}\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\,\mathrm dV\\
&=&\iiint\limits_{S_1}\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\,\mathrm dV+\iiint\limits_{S_2}\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\,\mathrm dV
\end{eqnarray}$

SPOILER!

> $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^3\int\limits_0^{\pi\over2}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}3\rho^2\sin(\phi)+2\rho^3\sin^2(\phi)\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\rho+\int\limits_0^2\int\limits_{\pi\over2}^\pi\int\limits_0^{2\pi}3\rho^2\sin(\phi)+2\rho^3\sin^2(\phi)\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\rho=70\pi$

Comment: Do you see the two half-spheres overlapping each other above the $z = 0$ plane?

Comment: I guess that term is wrong, i meant that one half-sphere is above the other one, so it looks like a cartoon-ish spaceship. http://www.how-to-draw-funny-cartoons.com/image-files/cartoon-spaceship-4.jpg

Comment: Ah, ok. I did one half-sphere above another like a half plum and I found $38\pi$ http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photos-plum-cut-half-image4889828

Comment: Well, your mistake is probably because you didn't see the minus sign on $z=-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ ...

Comment: Actually I saw, but I didn't accept it :) But you don't think that one of the integrals should be negative because of the normal vector?

Comment: Not at all, but consider using the plain definition of a surface integral in this exercise. It would require the parameterizations of 3 different surfaces.